# php page that opens based on checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have created a dropdown menu with 5 options. There are 6 checkboxes too on the same page along with a NEXT button(input type). The first option of dropdown on being clicked enables first three checkboxes and the second option enables last three (disabling first three) checkboxes. Now I want to open up different php pages for different dropdown options. 
Let me summarize up like i chose option 1 from dropdown menu and then check option 3 from checkboxes and the when i click on next only page targeted to option 1 from dropdown menu should get open. and there are 5 different pages for 5 options from dropdown. So it should be linked with dropdown and checked box that was checked should go into the database.

here is the code

```
    <select id="Objective" form="theForm" name="category" >
            <option value="0" selected="1">Choose from dropdown</option>
        <option value="bet">beta</option>
        <option value="theth">thetha</option>
        <option value="p">pi</option>
        <option value="ps">psi </option>
        <option value="alph">alpha</option>
    </select>

<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Laptops
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Computers 
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="2" /> Art 
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Computers Peri
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Movies
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="2"/> Beauty 

<script>
$("#Objective").on("change", function () {
    $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", false);
    if ($(this).val() == "theth") {
        $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "bet") {
        $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", true);

    }
}).trigger('change');

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Next' align='right'/>
```

I think I have made my ques clear and if still doubt persists please ask..

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it may have been a transcription error, but it appears the end script tag is missing. Also, for it to submit to your php file, be sure to have form tags that have the action required.

```
<form id="myform" action="yourphpfile.php" method="post">
<select id="Objective" form="theForm" name="category" >
    <option value="0" selected="1">Choose from dropdown</option>
    <option value="bet">beta</option>
    <option value="theth">thetha</option>
    <option value="p">pi</option>
    <option value="ps">psi </option>
    <option value="alph">alpha</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Laptops
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Computers
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="2" /> Art
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Computers Peri
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="1" /> Movies
<input type="checkbox" class="dissable" onclick="check();" value="2"/> Beauty

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Next' align='right'/>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#Objective").on("change", function () {
    $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", false);
    if ($(this).val() == "theth") {

        // update form action for theth
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'theth.php');

        $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else if ($(this).val() == "bet") {

        // update form action for bet
        $("#myform").attr('action', 'bet.php');

        $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {

        // assuming default means no change to form action

        $(".dissable[value='1']").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".dissable[value='2']").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
function check() {
  // what is this supposed to do?
}
</script>
```

I'm also unsure what the function check() is supposed to do.

Comment: for every option from the dropdown a different page has to be opened not just a single page "yourprofile.php". So i think form action won't work here.

Comment: i have closed the script tag just forgot to write it here :)

Comment: within your Object change function update the action like

    <form id="myform" ...
    $('#myform').prop('action', 'theotherphpfile.php');

Comment: will you please elaborate

Comment: sure, i've update the code with an example assuming your php files match the slug values, though they don't have to, of course.  does that help?

Comment: it is fine upto a level but pi, psi and alpha should also open teir respective pages instad of same page
alongwith that checkbox enable disable doesnt works the way it is supposed to do.

Comment: if i have helped you and given you info you need to make the changes you want, please mark the answer as the solution.

Comment: @sanchit updated it how? you should have what you need to write the code you desire. what are you still needing help with?